# Sonar issue Assignments should not be redundant (squid:S4165)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

```
private void updateEmployee(String employeeCode, UpdateUserDto updateUserDto){
    Employee emp = getEmpDetails(employeeCode);
    emp = updateMobile&Email(emp, updateUserDto.getMobile(), updateUserDto.getMail());
    // Remove this useless assignment; "emp" already holds the assigned value along all execution paths.

    ...
    ...
    emp.setisActive(updateUserDto.getIsActive());
    empRepo.save(emp);
}

private Employee updateMobile&Email(Employee emp, String mobile, String mail){
    if(emp.getMobile() == null && (mobile != null || mobile.isBlank())){
        emp.setMobile(mobile);
    }
    if(emp.getMail() == null && (getMail != null || getMail.isBlank())){
        emp.setMail(mail);
    }
    return emp;
}
```

Due to connectivity complexity I made some functions. Above one is just for example, the code is bigger

Remove this useless assignment; "emp" already holds the assigned value along all execution paths.

At line 2 of updateEmployee()

Sonar issue details

```
Assignments should not be redundant (squid:S4165)

Noncompliant
a = b;
c = a;
b = c; // Noncompliant: c and b are already the same

Compilant
a = b;
c = a;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emp parameter will be passed by reference into the updateMobile&Email method, meaning the line 2 assignment is unnecessary.

I suggest updating updateMobile&Email to have a void return type.